# Check if input empty on submit

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

I've been looking around for a solution to this, but can't seem to find any examples that work for me. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$("#register-form").submit(function(){
            if($(".required input").val() == '') {
                alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
                $(".required").addClass('highlight');
                // $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                return false;
            }
        });
```

For some reason, when I submit the form with none of the required fields filled in (there are two), then it works, but if one of them is filled out, it doesn't.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

osu

Comment: What does your html form look like?

Comment: (html5: use required attribute in input tag)Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865148/using-jquery-to-prevent-form-submission-when-input-fields-are-empty/39609587#39609587

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're only testing the first field you've got flagged as required. `$(".required input")` only returns the first input in your form that matches that selector.

This loops through all the inputs in the form that are flagged required (according to your selector). If it finds one with a value of '' then it sets the submit function to return false and highlights the blank fields. It also removes the highlight class from fields that are now valid but were previously invalid in an early form submit attempt.

```
$("#register-form").submit(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;

    $(".required input").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            isFormValid = false;
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });

    if (!isFormValid) alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");

    return isFormValid;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan - I had to do some fixing (unclosed parenthesis in places), but your solution made most sense to me. Here's the code I ended up with: http://www.pastie.org/1864757 Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: Ah I guess I did miss a couple closing braces/parens... glad I could help.

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#register-form").submit(function() {
  $('.required input').each(function() {
    if ($($this).val() == '') { 
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
    }
  });

  if ($('.required input').hasClass('highlight')) {
    alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Give that a shot.

EDIT
Moved the alert so users don't get their faces blown off with alert messages, good catch.

Comment: Beat me by a couple of seconds! +1, btw.

Comment: +1, move your alert above your `return false;` so it won't flood the user.

Comment: It has an error, will cancel submission of form only if the first element has `highlight` class.

Comment: @David: As Edgar stated, your last if condition is flawed. It will only check if the first required input has the highlight class.

Comment: @Edgar/Ryan: Did you try it?  Because with a simple test, it looks like jQuery will return true if any of the selected elements has the class. http://jsfiddle.net/qxhPn/

Comment: ..and from the jQuery docs: "Determine whether **ANY** of the matched elements are assigned the given class." (*Emphasis mine*)

Comment: Getting downvotes when the voters are wrong is always a drag :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple Solution !:

```
 function checkForm(){
        $("input.required").css("border","1px solid #AFAFAF");
        $("input.required[value=]").css("border-color","red");
        if($("input.required").val().length<2)return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your condition should be this:

```
if($("input.required").val() == '')... //Pay attention to the selector
```

Cause your selector was finding all inputs **children** of .required

Comment: This will only return the `val()` of the first matched input, just like the OP's code.  The only difference is that yours assumes a different html structure.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on David Fell's answer, (that has an error, in my opinion) you could do this:

```
$("#register-form").submit(function() {
  $('.required input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {           
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
    }
  });

  if ($('.required input.highlight').size() > 0) {
    alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: IMHO this is bad because it will alert the end user each time a required field is found that is blank.

Answer (score 0):

If the

```
$(".required input")
```

is matching more than one element, then

```
$(".required input").val() == ''
```

probably won't do what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the values of all the form inputs like that.

```
var valid = true;
$('.required input').each(function(){
   if( $(this).val() == '' ){
      valid = false;
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
   }
});
```

The [forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) will do this for you, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

name of the input or id in this case used id of the input

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="id"... />
```

JQUERY:

```
if (!$("#id").val()) {
   do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code get all form fields with **select list & checkbox** etc.

```
var save_prms = $("form").serializeArray();
    $(save_prms).each(function( index, element ) {
        alert(element.name);
        alert(element.val);
    });
```