# Validation on my form? "Please fill in required fields"

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a username form. Which have 2 fields, username and password.
Basically I want it so if the user has not entered the fields and pressed 'submit' an error displays like
"Please enter the required fields"

I know it's possible with JavaScript or PHP but unsure how to do it.

Here is the code of the user and password form:

```
<div id="sessionContainer" class="clearfix">
  <div class="content">
    <form action="goto.php" class=" sign-in" method="post">
      <div style="margin:0;padding:0"></div>
      <h3>Enter Details</h3>
      <p><font size="-1">Please enter your details</font></p><br>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <label for="">Username or email address</label><br>
        <input class="xlarge" id="email" name="email" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <label for=""><br>
          Password</label><br>
        <input class="xlarge" id="password" name="password" tabindex="2" type="password" value="" />
      </div>


      <p class="remember">&nbsp;</p>
      <p class="remember">
        <button class="btn btn-m btn-blue" id="signin_submit" name="commit" type="submit" tabindex=5>Sign in</button>
      </p>
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using jquery or just js? provide more info please

Comment: Please look into http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp for validation through javascript. Server side validation will not be efficient here.

Comment: @PiyasDe Why not? It's necessary anyways.

Comment: @PiyasDe you should use both... How does it make sense to only validate on the client end. Validation on the client end is more for UX honestly. You should always validate on the backend because client side can be tampered with and javascript can be disabled...

Comment: -1 for zero research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer...in clasic javascript xD:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function validar()
  {
     var right = 1;

     if(document.getElementById('email').value.length==0)
     {
        right = 0;
        document.getElementById('emptymail').innerHTML = "Empty Mail o Username";
     }
     if(document.getElementById('password').value.length==0)
     {
        right = 0;
        document.getElementById('emptypass').innerHTML = "Empty Password";
     }

    if(right == 1)
    {
      document.forms["formu"].submit();
    }

  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="goto.php" class=" sign-in" method="post" name="formu" id="formu">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0"></div>
        <h3>Enter Details</h3>
        <p><font size="-1">Please enter your details</font></p><br>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <label for="">Username or email address</label><br>
          <input class="xlarge" id="email" name="email" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" /><div id="emptymail"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <label for=""><br>
            Password</label><br>
          <input class="xlarge" id="password" name="password" tabindex="2" type="password" value="" /><div id="emptypass"></div>
        </div>


        <p class="remember">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="remember">
          <button class="btn btn-m btn-blue" id="signin_submit" name="commit" type="button" tabindex=5 onclick="validar();">Sign in</button>
        </p>

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: As Jeff stated above, Javascript can be tampered with, as well as disabled. Server-side is always the best way to go, IMO. ;-)

Comment: Thats ok...but in anyway you can have both ways...client side and server side...i do both ways...actually i use ajax anyway...and the term of using or not JS should be done in the initial part of the project;)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['password'])
```

This code will check if either of those fields has a value. If it does not, you can output an error message. The code in the whole context is as follows:

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['password']): ?>
    <div>Please fill in all fields!</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, where would this code be placed? In goto.php or will i have to make new file?

Answer (score 0):

HTML only solution using the [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute (works only in newer browsers):

```
<input required="required" />
```

An example how to do a jscript based solution can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp), [here](http://www.i-coding.de/www/en/javascript/form/input-validation.html) or [this one with a little jquery help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886555/check-if-input-empty-on-submit).

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) for validations

Download it from [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/) and call it. and then add this code

```
rules:
{
    email:
    {
        required: true
    }

},
messages:
{
    email:
    {
        required: "Please enter your email."
    }
}
```

**OR simply Use HTML 5 validations**

```
<input id="email" name="email"  type="text" value="" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it using JavaScript, you are looking for the OnSubmit attribute of your form

There are numerous things you can do if the function you called with OnSubmit fails (returns false), but as an example this code will show a popup box

```
<script>
function checkForm()
{
  if (document.getElementById('email').value.length==0 || document.getElementById('password').value.length==0)
  (
    alert("fill in required fields")
    return false;
  )
  return true;
}
<script>
```

Then in your form tag you put

```
<form onsubmit="return checkForm()" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $form = $('form'),
    $user = $('#email),
    $pass = $('#password');

$form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   // stop the default behavior
    if ($user.text().length === 0) {
        $user.addClass('error'); // do something with the error class or add attribute 'required'
    } else if ($pass.text().length === 0) {
        // do something else
    } else if ($user.text().length > 0 && $pass.text().length > 0) {
          // post the form
          $.ajax({
              url: //URL where you send,
              data: $form.serialize(),
              success: function(e) { // do something },
              error: function(e) { // do something }
        });
    }
}
```